# LaTeX Video Tutorials

Tags: support, feature-request

I am a not so beginner to LaTeX.I am aware of few classes and environments.But it took a lot of time for me to adapt to LaTeX.Documentations exists but are too heavy for a beginner.For example if I now want to lean *koma script* , I really find it a **hard nut to crack**.Can the tex.stackexchange.com provide video tutorials for basic introduction to the document classes of LaTeX and for finer tuning we can refer the documentation.May be I feel This is the only reason why LaTeX is not so popular among the masses.

Comment: If are willing to volunteer, Have a look at [Are any of you interested in starting an online LaTeX course?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3461/15717) and Related http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/3723/15717. Also follow/contribute to blog at http://www.texample.net/community/. IMO,getting to a stage with `texdoc koma-script` documentation itself is a big gigantic task which itself is a bonus for users. But to reduce the barrier still lower and lower... Users should make some effort by [Practice,Practice,Practice..](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/109969/15717) like any things in life.

Comment: So Maybe I think I will master koma scipt and help people out by answering questions and publishing articles.Is that ok?

Comment: I have not watched these myself but there is a collection of videos linked here http://www.texdev.net/2013/09/15/latex-tutorial-videos-from-sharelatex/